# Hash mining multiprocessing

Tags: python, hash, multiprocessing, pool, brute-force

I'm trying to solve a mining problem in python. Given a string `s` and an integer `z` I have to find the least `n` such that `sha256(sha256(x))` ends with `z` zeros where `x` is the string given by appending `n` to `s`. I wrote the following code:

```py
from hashlib import sha256
from multiprocessing import Pool

def solve(string, zeros, cores):
    with Pool(cores) as p:
        for i in range(cores):
            result = p.apply_async(sub_solve, args=(string, zeros, i, cores), callback = p.terminate)

    return result

def sub_solve(s, z, n0, cores):
    n = n0 - 1
    d = ""
    while d[:-z] != "0"*z:
        n += cores
        s1 = (s + str(n)).encode()
        h1 = sha256(s1)
        h2 = sha256(h1.digest())
        d = h2.hexdigest()
        if n % 100000 == 0:
            print("%d: %s" %(n,d))
    return n
```

Calling `solve` with `string = s`, `zeros = z` and `cores = number of cores to use` it should execute parallel `sub_solve` calls in different cores where each one should solve the problem for different `n`. When one of the working processes solve the problem the whole pool should terminate working.
When I run `solve` I get this output:

```
>>> pow.solve("asd",2,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\pow.py", line 7, in solve
    result = p.apply_async(sub_solve, args=(string, zeros, i, cores), callback = p.terminate)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 355, in apply_async
    raise ValueError("Pool not running")
ValueError: Pool not running
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration, the pool gets terminated due to the callback. So, In the next iteration there are no running Pool. To solve this, you will have to run the loop first and then use the `with` statement.

i.e.  swap the `with` statement with `for` loop like below:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from multiprocessing import Pool

def solve(string, zeros, cores):
    for i in range(cores):
        with Pool(cores) as p:            
            result = p.apply_async(sub_solve, args=(string, zeros, i, cores), callback = p.terminate)

    return result

def sub_solve(s, z, n0, cores):
    n = n0 - 1
    d = ""
    while d[:-z] != "0"*z:
        n += cores
        s1 = (s + str(n)).encode()
        h1 = sha256(s1)
        h2 = sha256(h1.digest())
        d = h2.hexdigest()
        if n % 100000 == 0:
            print("%d: %s" %(n,d))
    return n
```

Comment: Thank you, now I don't get the error but it doesn't work however. Running `>>> pow.solve("asd",2,4)
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x042372D0>`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score -1):

```
from hashlib import sha256
import multiprocessing

def solve(string, zeros, cores):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(cores) as p:
        for i in range(cores):
            ''' must call multiprocessing because the child process does Not know its p '''
            result = p.apply_async(sub_solve, args=(string, zeros, i, cores), callback = multiprocessing.Pool().close())

    return result

def sub_solve(s, z, n0, cores):
    n = n0 - 1
    d = ""
    while d[:-z] != "0"*z:
        n += cores
        s1 = (s + str(n)).encode()
        h1 = sha256(s1)
        h2 = sha256(h1.digest())
        d = h2.hexdigest()
        if n % 100000 == 0:
            print("%d: %s" %(n,d))
    return n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("sollving problem 1")
    solve("asdfk",2,8)
    print("solving probem 2")
    solve("abcdefhijk",4,8)
```

OutPut:

```
sollving problem 1
100000: b982a515ed1f9da8d11be880cd621e13aec777abf3e08c78dc0849d7d3e591c9
200000: bb495b542d5e89f82a464fee84e2ad33f18de9ad2817b233d292b77ae42ff584
300000: cb6e9e02de1f2b76250c47b5d7e1121bfb90d32451a7d75bfb538df76b427ab1
400000: da6cec93d44719ec44925365090b2b49e79ada037b1a64608fd855e83e3a08af
500000: 15b43eaa0a500a337d04f37a01b616e5068effacb807e27e760b97aa58b68147
600000: a97fc82597b7b80b1b2c29bbbeddea3eb93a8690728e596b29eef8aba02a2ec8
700000: 8647001bb6d7ba352e2cc24ed31a1bc858812ed864a208256c4f20078509a52d
800000: 08d55a3b590cba473f7391915824a38ac4c1012aebf29d0aad3d0ea5c0654c2d
900000: 8ca55f8e9585a7212ca494370f30738c2ba8ef2bc7fde6d8d182dbb079ecca0f
1000000: 7362508f0d1e3b0da1e6250dba8fee831d94dd9bfe2837935750f0deb10a1a08

solving probem 2
100000: 99dfca2809f20a173657d7f767573641b263a2a233d062001e4e979d944919d8
200000: 1d2a7ab78930756300a0061aa01489045ee2a51c4987c7364f6410811e102db1
300000: b326e26dcdd28c212880fe0dd83dcc9d41d9053bcad7c92263177c370d1131b7
400000: adbb9c6d8acaf680739f8b5e8c86efd68a9a2c7e62d54531123298e4329c2764
500000: f77358148f8dea09533111044b75032e45b77579f4fd567a23ad06b8c6f8d29a
600000: 1324e1d8e2883fe5b91c91e1a65d26218fb7c08b37c2804d2c904082d516a5e7
700000: 50cc0e97b1b91bad942d36c9f3c549978db4ecb666ea08ab9b9a20012ff2c14a
800000: b98e254395f26fbe4e60857f3cffe12a3751c991f705fb8f6b3853ac9aa20b13
900000: 1ea083e7c135040d60eb4b681b1aeb73425384b532e3ab2110f608b9db6b6c38
1000000: 89e8b62ce9ddfc12fb40ee1bfe82028a08c5aabb2184434128ff03b820e0c104
```